# error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'SEGMENT' in masm Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, syntax, masm

```
_DATA SEGMENT
 return_address dq  0
 real_rbx       dq  0
_DATA ENDS
```

I'm getting these two errors from this code, I'm not sure what is wrong with it, I'm using x64

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'SEGMENT'
```

Comment: Looks like you tried to compile this as C++ instead of assembling.

Comment: @Jester Under properties>general>item type its set to Microsoft Macro Assembler

Comment: and under build dependencies>build customizations masm is enabled

Comment: The error messages are totally unambiguous that it's treating this as C.  e.g. `int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int` is something only a C compiler would say about C (not C++); it makes no sense for asm.  Also, the error/warning code numbers  being C... instead of A.... are also a sign they're from MSVC compiler, MASM.  I don't use visual studio myself, but there is a canonical Q&A about all the project settings you need to get it to actually build .asm files as assembly, see the linked duplicate.